# suddenly facebook connect stopped working

Tags: php, facebook

A few days ago the facebook connection with our website stopped working all of the sudden, nothing was changed to the code???

Facebook made some changes???

http://www.presbium.sk/vstup-pre-uchadzacov/

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
    try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
     }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Comment: And when you say 'not working', at which point in the authentication flow does it stop working?

Comment: look here http://www.techmed.sk/kontakt  I put my login information, and after I am login in Facebook, but on page www.techmed.sk I am not connect. And befor everything working. I did everything as here:  github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk . Suddenly it stop working???

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything you need there:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

For login:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

for Facebook Connect:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Facebook Login is not an official Facebook expression. The official term for this is Facebook Authentication. Facebook Connect was the expression used for the server to server technology, back when the Rest API was up to date. Now, you have to use the Graph API to do the same things. You can find the infos about the old Rest API here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/

But consider these APIs are deprecated and using them for a new development is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for links,

but I have page with facebook autentification 1 year and suddenly it stopped working.

On page I have code as above, and facebook autentification don´t suddenly working.

I want to ask if somebody know why, becase I did nothing wihtn my code???

Comment: always glad to help :) 
It's not working because Facebook has made some internal changes to the system to increase the security. So all websites must revamp their code.

Comment: Thanx, and what I have to do. Is somewhere any advice what I must do with my code on page?

Answer (score 0):

There are changes to Facebook's API implemented continuously. Some of them may break your app's functionality. A good way to stay-up-to-date about what changes are happening is to following the [Operation Developer Love platform updates](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/11/28/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/). There you can find out about bugs and breaking changes to the API. Go through the latest blog updates to see if there is a change you have missed to implement.

Edit:

You wrote:

> I did everything as here github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk and befor 1 month it works but now it don´t working

The SDK github examples give you a blue print for a general case. The error is most likely something that's app specific, for example which permissions you ask for. I recommend you really go through all the 'breaking changes' in the blog for the past 3 months and see what it can be. For example, the 'offline access' permission was removed a while ago. If your app still asks for it, the apps expected behaviour may break. There are also new requirements for having a privacy policy that if not met may cut off the app's access to parts of the API. I'm not saying these are the source of issue with your app, they're just examples. Real examples.

Comment: OK, but I did everything as here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk and befor 1 month it works but now it don´t working???